# How to query all children with Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to make cloud functions query my realtime database

My structure:

```
devices_token
   -LuYV_1o8E6hC1hF-STo
       fcmToken:fFLk85eSHyk:APA91bHjRHP0aVH72r0GOeV51nUfpt-REYO..."
   -LuZwn7CQ3SVDWep9aOq
       fcmToken:"fFLk85eSHyk:APA91bHjRHP0aVH72r0GOeV51nUfpt-REYO..."
```

My code:

```js
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  let {title, id} = req.body;
  admin
  .database()
  .ref('/devices_token/{push_id}')
  .on('value', snapshot => {
    const val = snapshot.val();
    console.log(val);
   });
  });
```

And I'm getting `null`

Comment: what is `push_id`?

Answer (score 2):

I already solve it

```
admin
.database()
.ref('/devices_token')
.once('value', snapshot => {
  snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
    let val = data.val();

    push_token.push(val.fcmToken);
  });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use wildcards in Realtime Database refs. Instead I think what you're wanting to do here is just fetch the entire tree at `/devices_token` like so:

```
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
let {title, id} = req.body;
admin
.database()
.ref('/devices_token')
.once('value', snapshot => {
  const val = snapshot.val();
  console.log(val); // {"-LuYV_...":{"fcmToken":"..."},"...":{...}}
 });
});
```